# how to get respective image in url for asp.net website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to get our company image before the url in asp.net website
  for example in google [before](http://www.google.co.in/)  google image appeears

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to add a favicon in the root of your web application. Browsers will request that file and if it exist, they will show the icon before the url. In order to be compatible with most browsers, you will need to create a .ico file (this is, favicon.ico)

Here there's more information on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 1):

insert the following code into the *head* section of your page with the respective image/icon:

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />
```

In order to support cross-browsers you should create and use .ico file instead of *.png as in my exapmple. Try the free *.fav icon creator on-line service: http://www.favicon.cc/